# how to handle Access Denied or unauthorized response from api in client application with DI and Service pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, service

I am using DI and service based architecture so in this I created service for module wise like Category.
In my solution, services in one project in Visual studio, UI one project. my service code is

```
public virtual async Task<Category> GetCategoryDetailsById(string token, int id)
{
    var PathURL = _workContext.ApiEndPoint;
    Category response=new Category();
    string str = "Bearer" + " " + token;
    string r = Convert.ToString(str);
    string data= await _apiClient.GetClientAsync(str, PathURL, string.Format("/api/v{0}/Category/Get/", _workContext.ApiVersion) + id);
    if (data.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        _workContext.SetCookie("authentication", "false", 100);
    }
    else
    {
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data.Content);
    }
    return response ;
}
```

now in this method getting Unauthorized based on given permission to user so how to return to UI from this service project to my UI project which both in same solution.
so accordingly i can show or redirect to user access denied.

Comment: Well, you have a number of options to communicate this back to the caller: 1) return something like an UnauthorizedCategory 2) set a value on some shared state (if there is any) or as a last resort 3) throw an exception

Comment: @stuartd This code is working if i check every response so i can redirect from controller. Api access code in my Service pattern so its not possible to check every httpClient request by middleware or filter in application?. I have tried but i have only application context so this is not working because im connecting out side of application with restsharp so in pipeline of application need to check only httpclient. As I'm thinking i don't know is right or wrong.

Comment: _its not possible to check every httpClient request by middleware or filter in application?_ - if that's a question then it **is** possible, just add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to your startup program and inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your service layer.

Comment: but still we depends in service layer so we can wrap the network layer so we can redirect from middleware